# Load a DataGrid's row with my UserControl's content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I have this `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ButtonsDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,0,0"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          Background="Transparent" HeadersVisibility="None"
          BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="user_buttons">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <userButtons:GuestButtons/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

and the `XAML UserControl` that I need to put inside of that `DataTemplate`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HP_hf_shop.BrowseButtons.GuestButtons"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HP_hf_shop.BrowseButtons"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Template="{DynamicResource TileTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Path Data="M1.5,38.001 L10.666,38.001 10.666,38.005341 C10.666,38.011758 10.666,38.015 10.666,38.015 L57.666903,38.001107 67.909877,38.001 67.909877,81.667664 1.5,81.667664 z M34.188718,1.5000001 C46.680964,1.4988451 57.432162,7.8204405 57.710986,14.7386 57.917159,19.854203 57.674712,37.439694 57.667087,37.987992 L57.666903,38.001 10.666,38.001 10.666,37.976643 C10.665999,37.189652 10.665995,24.468745 10.666321,16.211438 10.666653,7.8482163 20.950168,1.501225 34.188718,1.5000001 z" 
                Style="{DynamicResource MimicVectorStyle}" Stretch="Fill"  StrokeThickness="3" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin"
                   Margin="5,2,5,2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   Content="REGISTER" FontSize="30" FontFamily="CenturyGothicRegual"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource MimicLabelStyle}">
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that nothing appears inside of the `DataGrid` row even if the `button` inside my `UserControl` is visible inside the designer. Later on this will have to be dynamic, that's the reason I don't just type the buttons inside of the row I mentioned as I'll have a list of buttons for guests, admins and customers. So again, how to make that `XAML UserControl`'s contents appear inside a row of my `DataGrid`?

I added

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

inside the `DataGrid` but the problem persists.

The code compiles and runs without any errors.

I created a whole new solution and copy-pasted the XAML code from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), nothing changed. It doesn't give their results even when I run the project. I'm on Visual Studio 2015, shall I reinstall?? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the sample and to make it work I fixed two issues:

1) DataGrid doesn't have ItemsSource set. How to fix:

xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ButtonsDataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=???-some-collection-from-DataContext}" ...
```

or code:

```
ButtonsDataGrid.ItemsSource = someCollection;
```

2) with ItemsSource set I got XamlParseException. DataGridTemplateColumn should be added to DataGrid.Columns, not directly to DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="user_buttons">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <wpfDemos:GuestButtons/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried to make it work in my case but I couldn't unfortunately. I made sure that the `DataContext` is set properly for **not just the UserControl but the Window it's called from as well** but not luck (checked that in debug mode). code behind is fine for me, shall I avoid using my `GuestButtons` usercontrol?

Comment: usercontrol in a TemplateColumn is fine. I suspect there should be an issue elsewhere (my best guess is incorrect binding for ItemsSource). does DataGrid show anything with `ButtonsDataGrid.ItemsSource = new int[] {1,2,3};` set in window constructor? that's what I did when tried your code from question

Comment: Yep, it works and shows me 3 of the given button I want. Bit off formatting but I will correct that. Now, how is that I put integers inside but got 3 buttons?? Or this would work just fine?

Comment: Uhh. I technically spent the day messing with this as I heard somewhere that for frontend one should stick to XAML. Now I removed the DataGrid, added a common Stackpanel and added a random button from codebehid. It works just as it should and took like 30 secs. Feeling a bit dumb, but I will stick to codebehind for most cases. But you solved my problem, so thanks!